# Synchronizing on a passed object, JFrame is freezing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, synchronization, wait

I created `JFrame` which contains and `InternalFrame` which draws figures which are moving(each figure is another `Thread`) I wanted to `pauseButton`make it pause, so I wanted to synchronize them on the passed object.

But when I hit the pause button the whole window is freezing and I cannot hit the play button
Another thing is that only one is running at the time, I want them all running then all pause.

```
 class A extends JFrame{

    ....
    Object o = new Object();
    JButtton pauseButton = new JButton("pause");
   JButtton playButton = new JButton("play");
    B b = new B(o);
        pauseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                synchronized (synchronizator) {
                    try {
                        synchronizator.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                }

            }
        });
        playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                synchronized (synchronizator) {
                    synchronizator.notifyAll(); 
                }

            }
    ...
    }
```

---

```
class B extends JInternalFrame{
Object o;
B(Object o){this.o = o}
./...

many... C thread = new C(o);

....
}
```

---

```
    class C extends Thread{
    Object o;
    booolean running;
    public void run(){
    while(running){
       synchronized(o){


       }
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: `which draws figures which are moving(each figure is another Thread)` please why, are those thread connecting Database, RMI, Socket, read FileIO ???, if not then use only one Swing Timer as already suggested by @Tom Hawtin - tackline, tons code example here about put all (prepared) Objects to arrays and inside paintComponent to pick_up Objects from array based on whatever conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noooo!! ;)

All Swing activity should be done on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Use normal thread-agnostic objects and perhaps `javax.swing.Timer` (not `java.util`!) for timing.

You may want to do other things not involving Swing on different threads, but I suggest keeping a really clean separation. That is to say very few objects should be dealing with thread issues.

If you are using the bare low-level Java synchronisation facilities, set a condition prior to `notify`/`notifyAll` and put your `wait`s within `while` loops.

Comment: and reason why SwingWorker is implemented in official API

Comment: @mKorbel What do you mean by that? `SwingWorker` has been in the Java library for years. However, I wouldn't recommend it as unnecessarily ties your code together.

Comment: Could you please show how use that timer if I have a ActionListener in class A and I want to pause `run()` in class C.(main post)